# Voltage of SODIMM DDR3 slots

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3, voltage, sodimm

I found conflicting information on the
usability of a SODIMM DDR3L module, low voltage (1.35v), as a replacement for a DDR3 module (1.5v), including the mention from someone who has a computer store.

That brings a question on the memory slots themselves:

**Are there motherboards that can operate memory slots at two different voltages (1.35v or 1.5v), or is that voltage always fixed at either 1.35v or 1.5v?**

Comment: check your motherboard HCL, and buy chips off that list.

Comment: The edit makes this question a hardware recommendation request, which is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

DDR3L (1.35V) RAM can be used with 1.5V and 1.35V motherboards.
DDR3 (1.5V) RAM can ONLY be used in 1.5V motherboards.

To my knowledge there are no motherboards that offer both variants.
It is one or the other.